# How to count the frequency of elements for unique combinations of columns and store in another column in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, frequency

I have a pandas dataframe containing 3 columns `id1`, `id2`, `call_freq` where the data is of below form

**Input:**

```
id1 id2 call_frequency
1   1   2
1   1   3
1   1   3
1   1   3
1   1   3
1   2   5
1   2   5
1   2   4
2   1   9
2   2   6
2   2   6
2   2   7
2   2   7
2   2   7
2   2   7
```

**Output:**

[image]

**call_frequency_dict** column should contain a dictionary string with elements 
in call_frequency for the combination of `id1` and `id2` and their frequencies as values.

I tried searching but found nothing helpful. How can I get the **call_frequency_dict**?

Comment: You want a dict? That's not a desirable output for pandas, there are many other ways to represent the frequency.

Comment: A string containing dictionary of frequencies so that I can refer to the dictionary later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will recommend using `value_counts` rather than push those type of data into a `dict`

```
df.groupby(['id1','id2']).call_frequency.value_counts()
```

To match your output

```
import collections 
df.groupby(['id1','id2']).call_frequency.agg(collections.Counter).reset_index()
Out[55]: 
   id1  id2 call_frequency
0    1    1   {2: 1, 3: 4}
1    1    2   {5: 2, 4: 1}
2    2    1         {9: 1}
3    2    2   {6: 2, 7: 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Good old `for` loop

```
d = {}
for i, j, f in zip(*map(df.get, df)):
    x = d.setdefault((i, j), {})
    x[f] = x.get(f, 0) + 1

result = pd.Series(d).reset_index()
result.columns = df.columns
result

   id1  id2 call_frequency
0    1    1   {2: 1, 3: 4}
1    1    2   {5: 2, 4: 1}
2    2    1         {9: 1}
3    2    2   {6: 2, 7: 4}
```